# Problem with OpenLayers and processing WKT geometry - ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, openlayers

A bit lost as to what is wrong.  I have a List in C# that I'm trying to iterate through in a foreach loop in my cshtml file.  My looping code is:

```
debugger;
@foreach(CheckInWeb.Models.Geo.cGeoPoint item in ViewBag.Geometries)
{
    <text>
    var wkt = @item.Geometry;
    var feature = wktReader.readFeature(wkt);
    feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');       
    feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            anchor: [0.5, 46], anchorXUnits: 'fraction', anchorYUnits: 'pixels', opacity: 1.0, scale: 0.5, src: '@Url.Content("~/images/Icons/marker.png")'
        })
    }));
    featureCollection.push(feature);
    </text>
}
```

The line that is crapping out in the browser is `var wkt = @item.Geometry;` with the error in the browser console window of: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

The rendered script in the browser looks like this:

```
debugger;

    var wkt = POINT (69.059 34.5411);
    var feature = wktReader.readFeature(wkt);
    feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');       
    feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            anchor: [0.5, 46], anchorXUnits: 'fraction', anchorYUnits: 'pixels', opacity: 1.0, scale: 0.5, src: '/images/Icons/marker.png'
        })
    }));
    featureCollection.push(feature);
```

Since `@item.Geometry` is a string, I've tried wrapping that input to the variable in single and double quotes with no change.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be easier to convert `ViewBag.Geometries` to a javascript array using `var geometried = @@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.Geometries));` (need to include `@inject IJsonHelper Json;) and do all this in a script

Comment: @StephenMuecke - how does that work when you have a List<T> where your class contains elements of:

- Geometry
- Name
- Time
- Color

Eventually I want to use those other elements to determine the icon, color, etc of the point

Comment: It serializes your `List<T>` to a javascript array - and then you can just loop through it and access each property of each item

Comment: @StephenMuecke

Thanks - that worked!

Comment: Answers do not go in the question. You need to add your own answer (and delete it from the question)

Answer (score 0):

**** FINAL SOLUTION *****

As suggested by Stephen, converting over to an array first does indeed make it easier:

```
var geometried = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.Geometries));
for (var i = 0; i < geometried.length; i++) {
    var feature = wktReader.readFeature(geometried[i].geometry);
    feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            anchor: [0.5, 46], anchorXUnits: 'fraction', anchorYUnits: 'pixels', opacity: 0.75, scale: 0.25, src: '@Url.Content("~/images/Icons/marker.png")'
        })
    }));
    featureCollection.push(feature);
}
```